# Help with installation on system with SSD and HDD

Tags: bootloader

So, I've read lots of threads here about dual booting between Ubuntu and Windows. I am a gamer, so I am chained to Windows.

I have an SSD with Windows 7 installed. I also have a HDD which is used for file storage. I have added another SSD and would like to install Ubuntu on it. I have the Ubuntu installation media on a flash drive.

I want it to look like this:

- SSD Windows
- SSD Ubuntu
- HDD NTFS file storage

I want to dual boot Ubuntu alongside Windows without messing up the Windows drive. Which drive do I need to put the bootloader on?

Comment: Can you actually boot from any/all of the listed drives?  If you can boot from the Ubuntu SSD, putting grub on it will allow you to remove the drive and still have the Windows SSD boot (assuming that's what you have now).

Comment: I currently boot from the SSD with windows installed. I want the option to chose between booting to the windows drive or booting to the Ubuntu drive. The HDD is for storage only.

Comment: I am at the part of the Ubuntu installation where it wants a drive to install Ubuntu to and below that it wants a device for the boot loader. Do I need to put the boot loader on the SSD with windows or the SSD with Ubuntu?

Comment: the grub bootloader will allow you to boot either Windows or Ubuntu if put on the currently booting SSD (replacing the Windows bootloader).  If you don't want to touch the Windows bootloader, and you can boot from the second SSD, (you can put it before the first SSD in the boot order in your BIOS)  you can put grub on the second SSD, and boot either Windows or Ubuntu from it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I decided to put the boot loader on the drive with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

The grub bootloader will allow you to boot either Windows or Ubuntu if put on the currently booting SSD (replacing the Windows bootloader). If you don't want to touch the Windows bootloader, and you can boot from the second SSD, (you can put it before the first SSD in the boot order in your BIOS) you can put grub on the second SSD, and boot either Windows or Ubuntu from it.